# npm install jsbin gives error

Tags: node.js, npm, jsbin

I am trying to install jsbin.
Doing it with jsbin.

I get the following error.

Iam doing it in linux.The command i used is

```
sudo npm install -g jsbin
```

I get this error

```
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
/usr/local/bin/jsbin -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsbin/bin/jsbin

> jsbin@4.0.3 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsbin
> grunt build

>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "concat" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! jsbin@4.0.3 postinstall: `grunt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jsbin@4.0.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/numan/.npm/_logs/2017-12-18T12_29_50_208Z-debug.log
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the jsbin repository to your machine.

Go in `jsbin` folder and do `npm install`.

There are more details https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md#node

I had the same problem by installing it with npm install -g jsbin, but by cloning the git repository it worked properly.

Comment: It worked. But now i get Another error.This one in during configuration.

Comment: Its Done Thank You.